# How to fix syntax error unexpected 'C'?

Tags: php

Hey I have to use a rename function to move a file being hosted by my xampp server.

I get an error on the third line that says:

```
syntax error, unexpected 'C' (T_STRING)
```

Please help, I have been trying for hours. Thank you so much!

```
   $indexsendphp = $AUTOIDQUERYRESULTROW[0] . ".php";

    $indexsendphp2 ="C:\xampp\htdocs\" . $indexsendphp;

    $indexsendphp3 ="C:\xampp\htdocs\SENDMEHERE\" . $indexsendphp;
```

Comment: You need to add an extra backslash to each one of those in your code.

Comment: why did you add the javascript tag earlier? if there is relevance, you should post it. Otherwise, others you may be misleading others who are expecting code for it and it doesn't help your post here as shown.

Comment: I'm wondering if you're still present here. Don't be shy; you can comment here.

Answer (score 2):

I know I voted to close, but I can't see the answer anywhere in the link I provided.

Your problem is that `\` is an "escape character" that means, in most cases (but not always) use the next character literally.

So you never close the quote as `\"` means use `"` as part of the string, and not what you meant it for.

Solution: escape the slashes, so they are not considered escape characters...

```
$indexsendphp2 ="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\" . $indexsendphp;

$indexsendphp3 ="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\SENDMEHERE\\" . $indexsendphp;
```

---

`"C:\xampp\htdocs\"` is the same as Start String, C, Colon, Literal x, a, m, p, p, literal h, t d,o,c,s, literal double quotes (NOT close String)... and the string is still open

`"C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\"` is the same as Start String, C, Colon, Literal slash, x, a, m, p, p, literal slash, h, t d,o,c,s, literal slash, Close String. Which is what you want.

A bit confusing at first.

Note that `\n`, `\t`, `\r` have special meanings.

Comment: so retract your vote (and the comment it created). I didn't bother posting an answer for this; I already wrote it in comments before seeing your answer here.

Comment: there's also nothing stopping you in posting what you wrote here in that canonical Q&A; it'd be a better addition there I feel and get more exposure.

Comment: Great job; on both counts. Cheers